# How to simplify $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} k \frac{x^k}{k!}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you go between these steps?

$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} k \frac{x^k}{k!} = x \sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$

Comment: $k/k!$=$1/(k-1)!$. Since the sum uses $k$ as a dummy variable, pulling out a factor of $x$ is allowed and $\Sigma_k x^{k}= x \Sigma_k x^{k-1}$

Comment: $k!=k\times (k-1)!$ could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use two simple facts:

- $x^{k} = x\cdot x^{k-1}$
- $k! = k\cdot (k-1)!$